# How to conditionally multiply rows in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumproduct

I need to obtain the product of all the rows that match with my query dynamically. I tried with sumproduct and vlookup but i have not got what im looking for. This is how it should be.

Thanks in advance!!

Data:

```
AAAs    3

AAAs    3

AAAs    1

ABC     3

ABC     4

ABC     2
```

Results:

```
ABC     24

AAAs    9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PRODUCT` + `IF` in array formula:

```
=PRODUCT(IF(A10=$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the crtl shift, thank you very much!!